# Can we define an inner product on the basis in any way we want?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

[image]

I have already shown the first part and I am trying to figure out whether there are any restrictions on how we can choose scalars for the inner product of basis elements. I was trying to come up with counterexamples, but having thought about this more, it doesn't seem like there are any so I think the answer is that we can choose any arbitrary scalar for $<e_j, e_k> $ and we would have an inner product. Is that true

Comment: No, not at all. For example, if you define $\langle e_j,e_j\rangle=-1$ you won't get an inner product. You also need to require symmetry/conjugate symmetry.

Comment: Ok yes that makes sense. Further clarification, but if each  <ej,ek> is itself an inner product, then it could be any arbitrary inner product, but once we have an inner product on the basis elements, and it actually is an inner product, then we can use that to define an inner product on the whole space right?

Comment: Saying that $\langle e_j, e_k \rangle$ for a given ordered pair is an inner product doesn't make sense. To be an inner product is a global property.

Answer (score 4):

By definition of an [inner product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space), $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is an inner product if and only if the matrix $(\gamma_{jk})$ is symmetric positive definite if you are dealing with real spaces. The matrix has to be Hermitian positive definite if you deal with complex spaces.

[A link](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Ezwick/Classes/Fall2012_2270/Lectures/Lecture33_with_Examples.pdf) on a way to check if a matrix is positive definite.

Comment: @Arthur Indeed. Answer updated.

Comment: oh, thanks! I forgot about the positive symmetric requirement.

Comment: @ mathcounterexamples.net , a quick point though,  do we need to assume an orthonormal basis for these requirements?

Comment: @William Not at all! If the basis would be orthonormal, the matrix would be very simple. Do you see what is the matrix of an inner product on an orthonormal basis? You just need to apply the definition of an orthonormal basis to see that.

Comment: ok thanks, because i remembered that the conjugate transpose of a matrix represents the self adjoint operator, but this only works for orthonormal basis, so I wasn't sure if we needed that in this case.

Comment: if the basis were orthogonal, the standard dot product is basically the only way to define an inner product that makes sense no? All the cross terms would cancel out. Or the matrix would be a diagonal matrix.

Comment: In an orthonormal basis, the matrix of the inner product is the identity matrix as $\langle e_i,e_j \rangle$ equals $0$ for $i \neq j$ and equals $1$ if $i=j$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  In infinite dimensional space is it true?